# How to select an element within an embedded object?

Tags: object, css-selectors, embed, overflow

I have a website where I am embedding another website as follows:

```
<object data=http://example.com width="600"              
height="400"> <embed src=http://example.com/> </embed> Error:  
Embedded     data could not be displayed. </object>
```

I would like to be able to hide the overflow, using overflow:hidden, but if I give the object an id, and reference it, this doesn't work. When testing with Firebug, if I set the child element of object, html (because I am embedding a web page), to overflow:hidden, this works. So my question is, how can I select the child of this embedded object so that I can turn the overflow to hidden?

Many thanks!

Alex

Comment: What do you mean by child, exactly?

Comment: By child I mean the next element inside of the object (the website). For example, if I look at it in Firebug, if I look at the contents of the object, I see the HTML markup for the embedded page. If i set the html element to overflow:hidden, this works. I can't seem to get this to work from my code however (not on Firebug). Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot select it with css (I'd be more than happy if somebody prooves me wrong on that), but you can access it with javascript:

```
var obj = document.getElementById("obj"); // assuming you object has id "obj"
var doc = obj.contentDocument; // get the inner DOM
var el = doc.getElementById("d1"); // assuming the embedded document has such an element
el.style.background = "green";
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kGce2/